# How to define the different template structs with different enums

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums, c++14

I've two enums as below:

```
enum TTT {t = 2};

enum XXX {x = 2};
```

I'm trying to make some struct to help me get the name of an enum. Here is what I've done:

```
template<TTT>
struct StrMyEnum {
    static char const* name() { return "unknown"; }
};

template<>
struct StrMyEnum<t> {
    static char const* name() { return "tt"; }
};
```

It works. Now I can get the name of the enum `t`: `StrMyEnum<t>::name()`.

However, if I write another group of template structs for `XXX`, it doesn't seem to work.

```
template<XXX>
struct StrMyEnum {
    static char const* name() { return "unknown"; }
};

template<>
struct StrMyEnum<x> {
    static char const* name() { return "xx"; }
};
```

Now I get a compile error: `could not convert 'x' from 'XXX' to 'TTT'`. It seems that the compiler is trying to match the `StrMyEnum<x>` with `TTT`...

I don't know why.

So template can't distinguish the different enums? Is it possible to write some structs for different enums?

Comment: Adding `StrMyEnum<XXX>` is redeclaration. Not just enums your code would not compile for any other type. https://ideone.com/E4XpXF

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3892a8b9af8d546 Not sure its exactly what you were going for though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StrMyEnum` identifies the name of the template.
You can have a general declaration for it, and then some specializations.
But you cannot have a second set of declaration + specializations (like you did with the set for `XXX`).

What you can do is have one template parametrized with both the enum type and the enum value.
Then you can have 2 levels of specializations:

1. For a specific value of a specific enum.
2. Default for a specific enum.

See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

enum TTT { t = 2, t2 = 3 };
enum XXX { x = 2, x2 = 3 };

template <typename T, T val>
struct StrMyEnum {
    static char const* name() { return "unknown"; }
};

// Default specialization for TTT:
template <TTT t>
struct StrMyEnum<TTT, t> {
    static char const* name() { return "TTT"; }
};

// Specialization for TTT::t:
template <>
struct StrMyEnum<TTT, t> {
    static char const* name() { return "TTT::t"; }
};

// Specialization for XXX::x:
template <>
struct StrMyEnum<XXX, x> {
    static char const* name() { return "XXX::x"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << StrMyEnum<TTT, t2>().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << StrMyEnum<TTT, t>().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << StrMyEnum<XXX, x2>().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << StrMyEnum<XXX, x>().name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
TTT
TTT::t
unknown
XXX::x
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zW547T9nf.

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++17 Non-type template parameter and make a partial specialization for `t` and `x`, since they are actually different types

```
enum TTT { t = 2 };

enum XXX { x = 2 };

template<auto>
struct StrMyEnum {
  static char const* name() { return "unknown"; }
};

template<>
struct StrMyEnum<t> {
  static char const* name() { return "tt"; }
};

template<>
struct StrMyEnum<x> {
  static char const* name() { return "xx"; }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/63anvhEjW)

Comment: Nice one dude, it helps but I can't use c++17 in my project...